# How long was Noah and his family in the ark?

Tags: noah

Well some of the numbers that I have seen about Noah in the ark don’t make sense  to me please help me out so I can have some understanding.

Comment: A full solar year (Genesis 7:11, 8:14). There is about a ten day difference between the Babylonian lunar year and the Egyptian solar year, which is what these verses are referencing.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

**How long was Noah and his family in the ark?**

The Deluge began- Noah entered the Ark

Genesis 7:11 (NASB)

> 11 In the six hundredth year of Noah’s life, in the second month, on
> the seventeenth day of the month, on the same day all the fountains of
> the great deep burst open, and the [a]floodgates of the sky were
> opened.

**Noah, entered the ark in the 600 th-year-old Noah's life, on the 17 th day of the 2nd month.**

The Deluge ended.

Genesis 8:13-14  (NASB)

> 13 Now it came about in the six hundred and first year, in the first
> month, on the first of the month, the water was dried up [a]from the
> earth. Then Noah removed the covering of the ark, and looked, and
> behold, the surface of the ground was dried up. 14 In the second
> month, on the twenty-seventh day of the month, the earth was dry.

**The deluge ended in the 601 st year of his life in the second month on the 27th day in other words Noah, spend one year and ten days in the ark.**

It appears from the scriptures that Noah used months of 30 days:

Genesis 8:3-4 (NET Bible)

> 3 The waters kept receding steadily from the earth so that they had
> gone down by the end of the 150 days. 4 On the seventeenth day of the
> seventh month, the ark came to rest on one of the mountains of Ararat.

Then the 12 months equal to  360 days, and the 10 days (Noah entered the ark on the **17 day** of the  2nd month on the 600 th year of his life and the land was dry on the 601st year of his life on the 2 nd month on the **27th day.**

Hence Noah spent a total of 370  in the ark, assuming that He left the ark in the morning of the next day.

Comment: [Noah's Flood narrative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_flood_narrative) exhibits [both Egyptian and Babylonian influences](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/revisions/39426/2).

Comment: Lucian: it does not surprise me, the scriptures say the catastrophic deluge of Noah happened  2.370 B.C.E and that Shem lived for 500 after the Deluge, and no doubt related the event to many generations. The flood-myth motif occurs in many cultures, Mesopotamian, Pralaya in Hinduism, Deucalion and Pyrrha in Greek mythology, Maya peoples in Mesoamerica. etc.

Answer (score 2):

The time in the ark is different depending on the narrative [1].

**J narrative**

7 days between entry into the ark and Flood start (Gen 7:7,10)

40 days of Flood (Gen 7:12)

40 days since the rain ceased (Gen 8:2b,6) to the 1st sending of the dove (Gen 8:8-9)

7 days to the 2nd sending of the dove (Gen 8:10-11)

7 days to the 3rd sending of the dove and subsequent exit from the ark (Gen 8:12,13b,20ff)

Total time in the ark = 7 + 40 + 40 + 7 + 7 = 101 days

**P narrative**

They entered the ark on the very same day the Flood began, Noah.600.2.17:

> In the six hundredth year of Noah’s life, in the second month, on the
> seventeenth day of the month, on the same day all the fountains of the
> great deep burst open, and the floodgates of the sky were opened.
> [v.12 belongs to J narrative.] **On the very same day** Noah and Shem
> and Ham and Japheth, the sons of Noah, and Noah’s wife and the three
> wives of his sons with them, entered the ark, (Gen 7:11,13)

They left the ark after the earth was dry, on Noah.601.2.27:

> In the second month, on the twenty-seventh day of the month, the earth
> was dry. Then God spoke to Noah, saying, “Go out of the ark, you and
> your wife and your sons and your sons’ wives with you. (Gen 8:14-16)

So, **if and only if** the same calendar was in effect during the year of the Flood, i.e. Noah.600, and the following year, the time in the ark would have been 1 year + 10 days. This is often interpreted in the sense that the calendar in use was the lunar calendar, whose year length is 354 days, while the time spent by Noah on the ark was a solar year of 365 days. But this interpretation is **incorrect** because in the lunar calendar the month length alternates between 29 and 30 days, while the P narrative says that, since the start of the Flood on **Noah.600.2.17**, **150 days** elapsed (Gen 8:3) to the moment when the waters had decreased enough to let the ark rest on Mount Ararat on **Noah.600.7.17** (Gen 8:4), **implying that all months from 2 to 6 were 30 days long**.

The most plausible calendar that in the P narrative is in effect during the year of the Flood is the 360-day calendar comprised of 12 30-day months, to which an extra month was added as needed to keep it in line with the seasons, used in Mesopotamia since ca. 2600 BC for administrative purposes and later also for astronomy. It was probably the assumed calendar in Daniel's prophecy of the 70 weeks of years, since we can understand the 1290 days of the second half of the last week of years (Dan 9:27 & 12:11) as simply due to the fact that one of those years is 390 days long (1290 = 360 · 3.5 + 30).

Since to achieve an average year length of 365 days an extra month must be intercalated every 6 years: (360 x 5 + 390) / 6 = 365, and since the year of the Flood was 1656 AM, which is divisible by 6, then the year of the Flood was 390 days long. Therefore, **if and only if** that calendar remained in effect during the next year, the time in the ark would have been 390 + 10 = 400 days.

But the chronology of the P Flood narrative can also be interpreted [2] as reflecting the transition from an old 360-day month-based calendar to a new 364-day week-based calendar, with the old calendar having been observed by the Sethian line of men since Creation up to, and including, the year of the Flood (1656 AM, Noah's 600th), and the new calendar becoming effective at the beginning of Noah's 601st year. Since 1656 years since Creation computed according to the old calendar comprised 10 more days than 1656 years computed according to the new calendar, a 10-day date adjustment occurred when the new calendar was enacted at the beginning of Noah's 601st year, just as a 10-day date adjustment occurred when the Gregorian calendar was enacted in 1582. Thus, whereas the date Noah.600.2.17 of the day when the Flood began was according to the **old** calendar, the date Noah.601.2.27 of the day when the earth was dry was according to the **new** calendar, so that it would have been Noah.601.2.17 in the old calendar. Thus, in this interpretation the time spent in the ark was 390 days.

**References**

[1] Project TABS (Torah and Biblical Scholarship) Editors, "A Textual Study of Noah's Flood", online [here](https://www.thetorah.com/article/a-textual-study-of-noahs-flood).

[2] Argentus, Johannes (2020), "The Priestly Flood chronology: a case of calendar replacement with Gregorian-like date adjustment", online [here](https://www.academia.edu/43988569/The_Priestly_Flood_chronology_a_case_of_calendar_replacement_with_Gregorian_like_date_adjustment).